# Closures javascript vs java

Tags: javascript, closures

I am learning javascript and I came across the following code snippet:

```
var outerValue = true;

function outerFn(){
  assert( outerFn && outerValue, "These come from the closure." );
}
```

Insofar as I understand closures in the above context, they allow the outerFn to actually see the outerValue variable.

My question then is: how is this any different from any other programming language - such as java for instance? It is just expected that outerValue's scope will allow outerFn to see it.

added later on:

```
    var outerValue = true;
    function outerFn() {
        console.log(outerValue);
    }

    function anotherFunction(arg){
        console.log("anotherFunction");
        arg.call(this);
    }

    anotherFunction(outerFn);
```

Is this then a better example of a closure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example does not really illustrate the difference, as you do not define the scope of outerValue. In Javascript, you may nest functions arbitrarily within one another, and closures make sure that inner functions can see outer functions even when invoked after the outer functions are no longer in scope.

In java, nesting functions is not (yet) legal, and thus closures do not even come into play. Having a class field in place of `outerValue` and a class method in place of your function is different, as the field of course is associated with the scope of the class, not the method.

Comment: thanks a lot Jonas. I have added a code sample to my question. I see that outerValue is still in scope!! This wouldn't be possible in java indeed!!

Answer (score 2):

Understand "clousures" as the ability to change the scope of execution of a function or method.
Here's an example where we run the same function by modifying the scope for 'client1' that 'May' and client2 which is 'John'. This is not possible in Java.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    function assert(condition, message) {
        if (condition) {
            alert(message);
        }
    }

    function testClousures() {
        var client1 = {name: 'Mary', code: 123};
        var client2 = {name: 'John', code: 234};

        function outerFn(){ 
            assert( this.name == 'John', "These come from the closure." );
        }

        // Testing if client is John 
        outerFn.apply(client1);  // Fail
        outerFn.apply(client2);  // Success

    }

    function domReady() {
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            testClousures();
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="domReady()">
<br/>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Test"></input>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: -1 This is exactly what is possible in java. You are not changing the context but this and that's the same as calling a method in java with diffrent objects.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the function `outerFn()` was passed as a callback. Sometime later when it runs, even though `outerValue` will have fallen out of scope, it will still be accessible within the closure.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Daniel but how do you know that "it will have fallen out of scope"? It wouldn't in another language such as java. Would it?

Comment: Can you provide a quick code sample of it being passed as a callback please? I find it difficult visualizing what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean that if I pass outerFn as an argument of another function, outerValue will still be visible within that other function? If that is the case, that's indeed interesting...

Comment: I have altered my code as you suggested. Thanks a lot to you.